# class TESTDLL_LIBSHARED_EXPORT TestDLL_lib

Tags: c++, c, qt, c++11, qt5

I'm beginning with [`QLibrary`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibrary.html), in this context I've reached the Stack Overflow question ["QLibrary - import a class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234327/qlibrary-import-a-class). And I have a question about that question:

What the meaning of `TESTDLL_LIBSHARED_EXPORT` in the class declaration?

```
class TESTDLL_LIBSHARED_EXPORT TestDLL_lib
{

public:
    TestDLL_lib();

    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    int getValues();
};
```

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555961/how-to-use-a-class-in-dll. for answer

Comment: I see Microsoft mentions in that question. Is it specific to Microsoft compiler? I'm using Qt/MinGW on Windows.

Comment: Oh, I think now I see, it must be a macro for ` __declspec(dllexport)`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [How to use a class in DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555961/how-to-use-a-class-in-dll) for detail answer.

> you can export data, functions, classes, or class member functions
>   from a DLL using the __declspec(dllexport) keyword.
>   __declspec(dllexport) adds the export directive to the object file so you do not need to use a .def file.   To export all of the public data
>   members and member functions in a class, the keyword must appear to
>   the left of the class name as follows:

```
class TESTDLL_LIBSHARED_EXPORT TestDLL_lib
```