# Object members not retrieved from a Qt dll

Tags: c++, qt

I try to get a QObject-subclassed object from a Qt shared library to a Qt application dynamically.

I have tried to apply a previous answer about this subject : [QLibrary - import a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234327/qlibrary-import-a-class)

Here is my common interface tabappinterface.h:

```
#ifndef TABAPP_H
#define TABAPP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>

class TabAppInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual ~TabAppInterface()
    {
    }
    QWidget *app;
    QString title;
};

#endif // TABAPP_H
```

My class dll-side mytabapp.h:

```
#ifndef MYTAB_H
#define MYTAB_H

#include "tabapp_global.h"
#include "tabappinterface.h"

class MYTABSHARED_EXPORT MyTabApp: public TabAppInterface
{
public:
    MyTabApp();
    virtual ~MyTabApp();
    QWidget *app;
    QString title;
};

extern "C" MYTABSHARED_EXPORT TabAppInterface *getTabApp();
```

and its implementation mytabapp.cpp:

```
#include "mytabapp.h"

MyTabApp::MyTabApp()
{
    app = new AppWidget();
    title = QStringLiteral("My Tab App");
}

MyTabApp::~MyTabApp()
{

}

TabAppInterface *getTabApp()
{
    return new MyTabApp();
}
```

My app-side implementation:

```
void ContainerMainWindow::loadLibraries()
{
    QLibrary myLib("mytabapp.dll");
    if(myLib.isLoaded())
    {
        qDebug() << "Loaded!";
    }
    typedef TabAppInterface *(*tabAppGetProt)();
    auto tabAppGetter = (tabAppGetProt) myLib.resolve("getTabApp");
    if(tabAppGetter)
    {
        auto *tabApp = tabAppGetter(); // not null
        qDebug() << tabApp->title; // print empty string
        qDebug() << (QWidget *)(tabApp->app); // SEGFAULT
    }
}
```

As stated in comment in the last lines, the object members are not retrieved although tabApp is not null.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `getTabApp` has 2 different signatures in h and cpp files, is that a copy paste error?

Comment: Kinda. Thanks tho. I tried to pass the object in parameter to see if there is any change. But no..

Comment: Btw, you forgot `Q_OBJECT` macro

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Right, thanks! Hoped it solve my problem but still no..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing the base class variables (fields) `title` and `app`, which nobody ever initialized. These variables aren't virtual at all, so those in the derived class just hide those in the base class. As a solution, you can declare them as protected in the base class and encapsulate them in getters and setters.

This way, your base class is like:

```
class TabAppInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual ~TabAppInterface(){}

    QWidget *getApp() const { return app; }
    void setApp(QWidget *value) { app = value; }

    QString getTitle() const { return title; }
    void setTitle(const QString &value) { title = value; }

protected:
    QWidget *app;
    QString title;
};
```

and the derived class is just like:

```
class MYTABSHARED_EXPORT MyTabApp: public TabAppInterface
{
public:
    MyTabApp();
    virtual ~MyTabApp();
};
```

You can still directly access the variables inside the derived class (i.e. initialize them in constructor) and through the getters/setters methods from outside:

```
    auto *tabApp = tabAppGetter();
    qDebug() << tabApp->getTitle();
    qDebug() << tabApp->getApp();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solve everything and my understanding of the subject is better.